# fadeout function along with slidetoggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

When I submit my form, the last function I have is:

```
$("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

This will show my thank you message for 5 seconds, and then fade the "message" div out.

I then tried adding this function below it:

```
$("#slide_panel").slideToggle("slow");
```

because I want the form (which is inside the #slide_panel div) to close / slide up AFTER the 5 second delay.... but when I add this function, its almost like the 5 second delay doesn't exist and the success message shows for about half a second and then the whole contact form dissapears as its supposed to.

What is wrong with my code?

```
$("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
$("#slide_panel").slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the code to the following ...

```
$("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(function(){
    $("#slide_panel").slideToggle("slow");        
});
```

That is, add the `slideToggle` of `SlidePanel` in the message callback. For more ideas, check http://jsfiddle.net/sf2Nr/1/

Comment: Thank dude!! I'm still learning jquery, trying to figure out how all is put together etc!

Answer (score 2):

delay function applies only to animation queue. you can use the following code by passing a call back function to `fadeOut()`

```
   $("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut('fast', function(){
         $("#slide_panel").slideToggle("slow");
   });
```

Now the slideToggle will run once the animation is completed.

Comment: Ah... I new it was passing a callback function. Was experimenting lastnite with that but I obviously didn't do it right! Thanks it works just perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the asynchronous behavior of the animation functions in jQuery.

In order to activate the `slideToggle` after the `fadeOut` delay, you must call it from the `fadeOut`'s callback function, i.e.:

```js
$("#message").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(0, function() {
    $("#slide_panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```